# Значение прилагательного «зябкий». Ударение

Tags: значение-слов, орфоэпия, прилагательные, лексическая-сочетаемость, неологизмы

> Мерзнет девочка в автомате,
> Прячет в **зябкое пальтецо**
> Все в слезах и губной помаде
> Перемазанное лицо.
> [А. Вознесенский. Первый лед](https://rustih.ru/andrej-voznesenskij-pervyj-led/)

> Тут было тихо и относительно уютно. Брошенная на дно охапка бурьяна защищала от **зябкой сырости** ([В. Быков. Журавлиный крик](https://books.google.ee/books?id=G5LPMY1DQgQC&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.&source=bl&ots=m9tOjWgnoV&sig=ACfU3U1A-plG52HFnrm5ffj5CezDFTdvog&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij3oPcwMLqAhWGtIsKHZCGD0gQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.&f=false)).

Пересмотрела [все словари](http://endic.ru/efremova/Zjabkij-30106.html), значение у прилагательного только одно: зябкий — чувствительный к холоду, быстро зябнущий.
И мне кажется, что к указанным контекстам оно не подходит.

Каково же значение слова "зябкий" в словосочетаниях "зябкое пальтецо" и "зябкая сырость"? Можно ли считать его [значение] неологизмом?
И еще. **Зя́бка** или **зябка́** (кр. ф.; ж. р.) — какое ударение считается правильным сегодня?

Comment: На ответ это не тянет, но я бы предложил посмотреть на употребление слова "зябкое" в литературе, например, через [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q="зябкое"&client=opera&hs=l6v&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&ei=KmcIX4T9CtSU1fAPt5GX4AM&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwiEuq3B38LqAhVUShUIHbfIBTw4FBDy0wMIRw&biw=1709&bih=854&dpr=1.1). "Пальто" (раньше Вознесенского) на глаза не попалось, но такие выражения, как "зябкое утро", "зябкое чувство" встречались задолго до него (у Горького и т.д.). Поэтому неологизмом я бы это не назвал...

Comment: "Зябкое пальтецо" - это просто эпитет. Поэт показывает, что лирической героине было холодно.

Answer (score 1):

Значения в обоих примерах вполне понятны: в первом случае это пальто, *в котором можно озябнуть при малейшей прохладе*, во втором - сырость, *от которой (всякому) можно озябнуть*. Такое употребление создаёт своеобразный художественный колорит и по форме мало чем отличается от условностей типа "холодное (тёплое) пальто".

Гораздо хуже воспринимаются канцелярские метонимии типа "мобильный телефон" и тем более "мобильное приложение", поскольку они навязчиво ассоциируются с буквальными смыслами: "телефон, который возят (он большой, но движимый; более точным и удачным было старое определение "карманный")" или "приложение, способное передвигаться".